# Circle UIView not created properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to create a simple circle view.
I did it before, and now for some reason the circle is not precise (image attached).
In my code i'm taking the height of the "sliderPin" view, and the half value of it goes for the cornerRadius of its layer.
I tried to take the constraint height value of the "sliderPin" view as well, but I got the same results.
* The width & height of the view are equal.
My code:

```
[self.sliderPin.layer setBorderColor:borderColor];
[self.sliderPin.layer setBorderWidth:2];
self.sliderPin.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.sliderPin.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[setCornerRadius:CGRectGetHeight(self.sliderPin.frame) / 2];
```

[image]

Comment: check your circle view height & width both are same?

Comment: Yes. the width and height are equal

Comment: Is it slider or switch? I means do you need slider or switch?

Comment: I suspect the height is not what you expect it is. Perhaps the slider is inset a bit (perhaps to give you a bigger hit test target for using the slider). You could probably use the visual debugger in Xcode, to confirm. Alternatively, there might be some transform in place, in which case you might use the height of the bounds instead of the frame. We'd need more info on this slider view and/or your use of this control, to help further.

Comment: @Rob - it think this is really the way to the solution. I checked with the `Debug view hierarchy` - and the height of the view is different from what i told it to be and from what the debug shows me. when I put the values as they are in the `Debug view hierarchy` the problem solved.

Comment: due to usage of autolayout constraints your slider size changed so please fixed size first width and height and than apply fram.height/2, i hope it will work fine. same happend with me

Comment: what do you mean by saying "fixed size first width and height " ?

Comment: try to put your code in layout subview

Answer (score 1):

Better to use UISlider, with given methods. It might solve your problem.

```
    UIImage *minImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_minimum.png"] 
        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
    UIImage *maxImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_maximum.png"] 
        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
    UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"];

         [[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage 
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackImage:minImage 
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:thumbImage 
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For Height:

You can customise by inheriting UISlider and over-riding method

```
- (CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30);//change it to any size you want
    return rect;
}
```

You can customise more by inheriting respective methods.

[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you control on the height of the UISlider ?

Comment: @AsiGivati, can you check answer now.

Comment: The method "trackReckForBounds" not called. + look how its look like, i need it to be with rounded sides. https://s10.postimg.org/68w45bokp/Screen_Shot_2016_08_22_at_1_36_35_PM.png

Comment: Did you put custom slider as Custom Class/ father class of your slider in storyboard??

Comment: Yes :) how can i do round corner like in your pic?

Comment: @VeerSuthar can you tell me?

Comment: I dragged UISlider, and make its parent file custom, and than put code, which I gave in screen shot, its by default rounded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `constraints`are not conflicting. If you are using `auto layout`, set `sliderPin`'s width and height equal constraints or aspect ratio 1:1 might solve the problem.